# What is the current state of the evidence of the existence of the so-called Nazi UFO's?

Tags: history, ufo

As a skeptic, I was present at a meeting during which the presenter stated his belief in [Nazi UFOs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nazi_UFOs).
Many websites claim that the Nazis had developed flying saucer technology during WWII:

> In science fiction, conspiracy theory, and underground comic books, stories or claims circulate linking UFOs to Nazi Germany. These Nazi UFO theories describe supposedly successful attempts to develop advanced aircraft or spacecraft prior to and during World War II, and further claim the post-war survival of these craft in secret underground bases in Antarctica, South America or the United States, along with their creators.
> --[source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nazi_UFOs)

[image: Nazi UFO]

Is there any evidence that can be described as remotely credible?

Comment: Would you mind citing people making those claims? The more information you give us about the claim you are skeptical of, the better the answers will be.

Comment: @ Borror0 The guy was the founder of www.niburu.nl, which, unfortunately, is mainly in Dutch. However, if you search (as I did) for "Nazi UFO", or "Nazi saucer" you will be overwhelmed with hits. You may also want to look for Vril and/or Haunebu, two specific types. The presenter in this case was also pretty adamant in that the UFOs had their base in holes in the earth's poles. Pretty crackpot case.

Comment: The **Discovery Channel** did a documentary on that. You can watch in on Youtube.

Comment: But the Discovery Channel is just Sharks and Nazis anyway: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w3m0qKiY_Ek

Comment: IRON SKY WAS TRUE ?!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As with any claim like this you have to look at the primary sources.

When it comes to the more recent versions of the Nazi saucer claims (ie. leaving the mystical Vril stuff out and concentrating on Die Glocke), [the only source is the Polish author Igor Witkowski](http://dir.salon.com/story/books/review/2002/08/05/zero_gravity/index1.html), who claims to have been shown by someone (he won't say who) a transcript of the interrogation of an SS officer who was protecting flying saucer research. Of course no one else has seen the alleged transcript, so it's hard to call that evidence for anything. UFO researchers eventually went to the site Witkowski gave for where the research was supposed to have been conducted, but the "mysterious structures" they found [were easily shown to be mundane building remains, even by other UFO researchers](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O8cXr3CchZU).

The idea that the Nazi have UFO bases inside the hollow earth also comes from a single source -- the alleged "Secret Diary" of Admiral Byrd. The diary, which showed up as a mail order item available from "The Society for a Complete Earth" sometime in the 1970s, claimed that Admiral Byrd had flown to the interior of the earth via the North Pole and encountered crystal cities full of UFOs and Aryans. Again, this single source is hardly credible and is contradicted by pretty much the entire historical record, but some UFO and hollow earth researchers like to claim that the diary is genuine, and Byrd, despite keeping it totally secret until after his death, changed the dates, maybe the places, and really meant Nazis when he said Aryans. In other words if you change every single thing the diary says, it's completely true. These kinds of researchers always wonder why they aren't taken seriously. You can read the whole saga of the diary from the believers perspective [here](http://www.thehollowearthinsider.com/news/wmview.php?ArtID=6), or in the book Admiral Byrd's Secret Journey Beyond the Poles by Tim Swartz.

The strain of Nazi UFO-ism that talks about Vril and Haunebu saucers, I'm not really sure where it comes from, but I didn't really hear about it until the internet. I suspect the website http://discaircraft.greyfalcon.us/ is the source, but I can't prove that. The author of that site (he calls it a book) doesn't really explain where any of his information comes from, and his odd tendency to sprinkle pictures of naked women into discussions of aircraft engineering has always made me wonder if the site is entirely serious. Still, I've never found any detailed information on the alleged Haunebu or Vril saucers that predates it.

Comment: Hi Scott! As you rightly suggest, we like to see the sources you refer to. We are skeptics, after all ;-) Please sustain your post with links to reputable sources as per our [policy](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/5/must-answers-be-referenced)! Thank you!

Comment: Thanks, did you see this one (http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5jl0N-TUUuQ), purportedly of the Haunebu 7?

Comment: SKlivvz - I added some links. It can be a little tough, though, because a lot of this material has very skeptical response. For example, I've never seen anyone do much of an analysis of the Admiral Bird's Secret Diary, simply because it's so ridiculous. When the diary has Byrd flying to the North Pole, Byrd was actually participating in the highly publicized Operation High Jump at the South Pole. What more is there to say about that? Writers like Swartz claim that diary is really a disguised account of something that happened during High Jump, but that's just unsupported speculation.

Comment: Sjoerd - I hadn't seen that video before, but without knowing where it came from what's to say? It was shot after 1976, because we hear the song Car Wash in the background, but beyond that it looks like a CGI object added into existing video. The uploader has some other videos, and the one from China features the people filming the UFO having what sounds to me a completely mundane conversation while extraordinary things happen in front of them. I'd say that's a slight credibility problem. Also, a "Nasa Moonlanding 1947" (sic) is a little bit impossible, because NASA was founded in 1958.

Comment: @scott This lack of excitement is also present in the video I linked to. As for CGI manipulation: might be, but then it's extremely well done. All the camera shakes are consistent with UFO and back/foreground movements. I tend to think it must be model based, perhaps with some image manipulation where the UFO seems to pass __behind__ the antenna. But again, very cleverly done.

Comment: @scott Nice observation about the music. I was already considering the SoundHound app to see whether it could make anything out of the very faint sounds, but you beat me to it. Anyway, I moved this video to a separate question.